# What's special about the greatest common divisor of a + b and a - b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Problem:

> Prove that if gcd( a, b ) = 1, then gcd( a - b, a + b ) is either 1 or 2.

From Bezout's Theorem, I see that am + bn = 1, and a, b are relative primes. However, I could not find a way to link this idea to a - b and a + b. I realized that in order to have gcd( a, b ) = 1, they must not be both even. I played around with some examples (13, 17), ...and I saw it's actually true :( ! Any idea?

Comment: +1 for showing some thought and trying something before posting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gcd of $x$ and $y$ divides any linear combination of $x$ and $y$. And any number that divides $r$ and $s$ divides the gcd of $r$ and $s$.

If you add $a+b$ and $a-b$, you get `<blank>`, so  $\mathrm{gcd}(a+b,a-b)$ divides `<blank>`.

If you subtract $a-b$ from $a+b$, you get `<blankity>`, so $\mathrm{gcd}(a+b,a-b)$ divides `<blankity>`.

So $\mathrm{gcd}(a+b,a-b)$ divides $\mathrm{gcd}($`<blank>,<blankity>`$) = $`<blankety-blank>`.

(For good measure, assuming the result is true you'll want to come up with examples where you get $1$ and examples where you get $2$, just to convince yourself that the statement you are trying to prove is the best you can do).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Haha, I got it. Much simpler than I thought. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, I can't go from gcd( a + b, a - b ) right? since this is inverse error if A then B, does not guarantee B then A. Should I prove it by contradiction instead?

Comment: @Chan: I'm not sure what you mean... You cannot begin by *assuming* that gcd(a+b,a-b) is equal to 1 or to 2, but you do not need to make any assumption. The hints above give you information about what gcd(a+b,a-b) must divide, and you have other information (remember what you are told about $a$ and $b$). All of that together should be sufficient (PEV was more explicit, and you seemed to think it was a great hint).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: All I tried to say is that, when proving if A then B. If we assume B is true, then infer A is true -> this is wrong.

Comment: Yes. You should never affirm the consequent. If you assume B is true and infer A is true, then you prove $B\rightarrow A$, which may be something interesting, but is not equivalent to $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: Thanks again for the confirm.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1/32894#32894) for a generalization using determinants and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1/33104#33104) using norms.

Comment: what does that mean <blank>,<blankity> <blankety-blank> ??

Answer (score 2):

Note that $d|(a-b)$ and $d|(a+b)$ where $d = \gcd(a-b, a+b)$. So $d$ divides the sum and difference (i.e. $2a$ and $2b$).

Comment: Thanks for a great hint ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ a\!-\!b + (a\!+\!b)\ {\it i}\ =\ (1\!+\!{\it i})\ (a\!+\!b\!\ {\it i})\ \ $ yields a slick proof using Gaussian integers. This reveals the arithmetical essence of the matter and, hence, suggests [obvious generalizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33104/242).