# Prove that $\gcd(p + q, p - q) = 2$ if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes. Prove that $\gcd(p + q, p - q) = 2$. 
I have considered EEA to multiply it out, but I'm unsure where to go from there.

Comment: you need $p \neq q$

Comment: See also: [Prove $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 1$ or $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 2$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32737)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need $p\not=q$ because $\gcd(3+3,3-3)=\gcd(6,0)=6$.

Since $p,q$ are odd, we know that $p+q,p-q$ are even. Thus, $2|p+q$ and $2|p-q$. Therefore, $\gcd(p-q,p+q)\geq2$. It remains to show that $\gcd(p-q,p+q)\leq2$.

Since $p,q$ are distinct odd primes, we have $\gcd(p,q)=1$. By Bezout's Identity, there exists integers $a,b$ such that $ap+bq=\gcd(p,q)=1$. Let $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$. Observe that $(p+q)x+(p-q)y=2$. Thus, by Bezout's Identity, $\gcd(p+q,p-q)\leq2$. This is what we desired.

Note: In some places, Bezout's identity is called GCD Characterization Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(p-q,p+q)=d$, then we definitely have $d \mid p-q+p+q=2p$. This implies that either $d=2$ or $d=p$. The last case implies that $p=q$, so if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, we must have $d=2$.