# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ , then $a-b$ does not divide $a+b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I think the  following statement is true:

> Suppose $a,b\in \mathbb{N}^+$, such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $|a-b|\geq\mathbf3$. Then $a-b$ does **not** divide $a+b$.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If positive integer $d$ divides  both $a+b, a-b$

$d$ must divide $a+b\pm(a-b)$

$d$ must divide $2(a,b)=2$

So, $a+b,a-b$ can not have a common divisor $>2$

But $|a-b|\ge3>2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Bezout Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) approach.

Assume that $a-b\mid a+b$. Then
$$
\gcd(a-b,a+b)=a-b
$$
Since there are $x,y$ so that $ax+by=1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(a-b)(x-y)+(a+b)(x+y)
&=2(ax+by)\\
&=2
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\gcd(a-b,a+b)\mid2$. Therefore, $a-b\mid2$, which contradicts that we are given $|a-b|\ge3$.

Therefore, our assumption that $a-b\mid a+b$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1?rq=1) we have if gcd$(a,b)= 1$, then gcd$(a-b,a+b) =1$ or gcd$(a-b,a+b) =2$.

Since $a-b\geq 3$ then gcd$(a-b,a+b) \neq a-b$, then $a-b$ does not divide $a+b$.