# Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be integers. Prove that if $4|(a+bc)$ and $6|(b+ac)$, then $2|(a^2-b^2)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

This is my work so far.

[image: work]

How can I isolate the $(a^2-b^2)$?

I am not asking for a full solution, just a hint and next step.

---

All done! Thanks Michael.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4|(a+bc)$ then $a+b c = 4k\to c=\dfrac{4 k-a}{b}$

$6|(b+ac)$ then $b+ac=6h$ plug $c$

$b + a \,\dfrac{4 k-a}{b}=6h$

$b^2+4ak-a^2=6bh$

$a^2-b^2=2 (2 a k-3 b h)$

Which means that $2|(a^2-b^2)$

*QED*

Answer (score 0):

The hint:
$$a(a+bc)-b(b+ac)=a^2+abc-(b^2+abc)=a^2-b^2$$

Comment: Very helpful Michael

Comment: @Max Li Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Worth explicit *emphasis:* the *key idea* is to **eliminate** $\,c\,$ as below

$$\begin{align}
2 = d\:\!\mid \color{#0a0}{bc}&\ +\ \color{#0a0}a,\ \ \color{#c00}{ac\ +\ b}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \bmod d\!:\:\!\ \color{#0a0}{bc} &\equiv\color{#0a0}{-a},\, \color{#c00}{ac\equiv -b}\\[.2em]
{\rm so}\, \ \ \  {-}a\,(\color{#0a0}{bc} &\equiv \color{#0a0}{-a})\\
 +\,\ \ \ \ \ b\,(\color{#c00}{ac}&\equiv \color{#c00}{-b})\,\ \ \textbf{[eliminates $c$]}\\[.2em]
\hline
\Rightarrow\ \ \qquad  0\,&\equiv\, a^2\!-b^2\  \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Or, $ $ without mod: $\, a(\color{#0a0}{bc\!+\!a})-b(\color{#c00}{ac\!+\!b}) = a^2\!-b^2\,$ is divisible by $\,d\,$ since the  colored terms are.

The point of using congruence *equation arithmetic* (vs. divisibility *relation calculus*) is that it transforms the problem into *equational* (vs. relational) calculations, where we have better intuition (e.g.  elimination taught in *linear* algebra).  Though the difference may seem minor here, exploiting well-known *linear* algebra methods will often greatly simplify matters for less trivial problems. For a less trivial example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32894/242) where we use Cramer's rule for elimination.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: consider what happens to the parity of the other numbers when $a$ is odd or even.