# Find all solutions in positive integers of the Diophantine equation $x^2+2y^2 =z^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I can't solve the following exercise. It's already on this site, but the solution method is not the same as in my solutions manual.

> Find all solutions in positive integers of the Diophantine equation $x^2+2y^2 =z^2$.

The solution is given, but I do not understand the italicised parts.

> **13.1.8** $2y^2=z^2-x^2=(z-x)(z+x)$. *$x$ and $y$ have the same parity*, so *$(z-x)/2$ and $(z+x)/2$ are integers*. It suffices to assume $(x,z)=1$. *Then either $((z-x)/2,z+x)=1$*, and then $y^2=((z-x)/2)(z+x)=m^2n^2$, and *solving $(z-x)/2=m^2$ and $z+x=n^2$ for $x$ and $y$ gives $x=(m^2-2n^2)/2,y=mn,z=(m^2+2n^2)/2$*. Or $((z+x)/2,z-x)=1$ which gives $x=(2m^2-n^2)/2,y=mn,z=(2m^2+n^2)/2$.

- Why have x and y the same parity?
- Why are $(z-x)/2$ and $(z+x)/2$ integers?
- Why do they assume $\gcd((z-x)/2,z+x)=1$ and next $\gcd((z+x)/2,z-x)=1$?
- How to solve $(z-x^2)/2 = m^2$ and $z-x=n^2$ for x and y to become the values for x, y and z?

[image]

Comment: If $x$ is even, what can you say about $x^2$? Can $2y^2$ be odd? If not, what can you now say about $z^2$? and about $z$?

Comment: @Mastrem How do we know if x is even or odd? $2y^2 is always even! If $z^2$ is even, then z is even, if $z^2$ is odd, then z is odd

Comment: You don't. However, what you CAN deduce is, that IF $x$ is even, THEN $z$ is even and in a similair way, IF $x$ is odd, THEN $z$ is odd as well. Therefore $x$ and $z$ are always of the same parity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $2y^2=z^2-x^2$, the left-hand side is an even number so $z,x$ must either both be even (even minus even is even) or they must both be odd (odd minus odd is even).  They did, however, mistype.  They typed $x,y$ have the same parity (false for some solutions) but meant $x,z$ gave the same parity (proven true here).
- $z-x$ must be even (by the argument above), so $\frac{z-x}{2}$ is an integer.
- $z+x$ must also be even by the exact same argument, so $\frac{z+x}{2}$ is also an integer.
- First they assume that $\gcd(x,z)=1$, because if they have a common factor, say $d$, then you have the expression:
  $$2y^2=(z'd-x'd)(z'd+x'd)=d^2(z'-x')(z'+x')$$ and you can divide both sides by $d^2$ and get exactly the same expression ($x=x'd$, $y=y'd$, $z=z'd$). At some point this has to stop so you can assume that $x,z$ have no common factor.
- This is perhaps the hardest part:
  Why is $$\gcd\left (\frac{(z-x)}{2},z+x\right )=1$$ or $$\gcd\left (z-x,\frac{(z+x)}{2}\right )=1$$ This follows from another result:

> If $\gcd(z,x)=1$ then $\gcd(z-x,z+x)$ is $1$ or $2$

The result is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1). Now, we know that both $z-x,z+x$ are divisible by $2$, and this is the largest factor they can have in common. **Atleast one** of $z-x,z+x$ is divisible by $2$ and **not** $4$. This means that we must have either $\gcd\left (\frac{(z-x)}{2},z+x\right )=1$ or $\gcd\left (z-x,\frac{(z+x)}{2}\right )=1$. Now, which one is it? We don't know!

1. If $\gcd\left (\frac{(z-x)}{2},z+x\right )=1$ then we know that $$y^2=\frac{(z-x)}{2}(z+x)$$
   but $y^2$ is a square, and $\frac{(z-x)}{2},z+x$ have no factor in common! This must mean that $\frac{(z-x)}{2}=m^2$ is a square, and $z+x=n^2$ is a square. You can use this information to solve for $x,y,z$.
2. If $\gcd\left (z-x,\frac{(z+x)}{2}\right )=1$ then again we know that $$y^2=(z-x)\frac{(z+x)}{2}$$
   but $y^2$ is a square, and $z-x,\frac{(z+x)}{2}$ have again no factor in common! This must mean that $z-x=n^2$ is a square, and $\frac{z+x}{2}=m^2$ is a square.

Comment: Thnx! Clear! But how can you solve $(z−x^2)/2=m^2$ and $z−x=n^2$ for x and y to become the values for x, y and z?

Comment: Ok, so rewriting we have $z-x=2m^2$ and $z+x=n^2$. If you add these to equations together you get $2z+0=2m^2+n^2$, dividing by $2$ yields $z=\frac{2m^2+n^2}{2}$. Now that you know what $z$ is, can you find out what $x$ is?

Comment: Thnx! I found it! There's just one thing not clear to me: First we say $y^2=((z-x)/2)((z+x)/2)$ and next we say $y^2=((z-x)/2)(z+x)$ and later on $y^2=((z+x)/2)(z-x)$. Why is this true?

Comment: @Elce I have updated my answer, please tell me if it is more helpful now!
We don't say that $y^2=\left ( (\frac{z-x}{2})(\frac{z+x}{2})\right )$, we start with: $2y^2=(z-x)(z+x)$, then we divide by the $2$. Now we can choose which factor to divide by $2$, and the result is still the same. For instance $\frac{4}{2}\times 6=2\times 6$ is still the same as $4\times\frac{6}{2}=4\times 3$. But notice that $\gcd(2,6)=2$ and $\gcd(4,3)=1$. So we are *choosing* to divide by the factor that gives a $\gcd$ of $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Jus one question: The solutions says $x=(m^2-2n^2)/2,y=mn,z=(m^2+2n^2)/2$ But I become other values. Are they wrong? I uploaded the picture!

Comment: @Elce everything you have done seems perfect. I'm sure the book have made some typos.