# $s$ and $t$ are odd and relatively prime. Why is $2$ the only common factor of $s-t$ and $s+t$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this in textbook Silverman (2012) *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* on page 232 without explanation. They make it sound so obvious so I must have missed something along the way.

The way I know to find common factors between two numbers is prime factorization and Euclidean algorithm (but I do not know how to apply them in this situation). I mean $s-t$ and $s+t$ must be even, this I know how to easily prove.

But I can't figure out why their only common factor must be $2$. Please help!

Comment: Hint:  if $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then $d\,|\,(a+b)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 1$ or $2\,$ if $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-2-if-gcda-b-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(m%2Cn)%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(m-n%2Cm%2Bn)%3D2%24&p=1). Since $s$ and $t$ are odd, then $s-t$ and $s+t$ are both even, as you've already noted, so this means $\gcd(s-t,s+t)=2$. Note another duplicate (among quite a few) is [Suppose that$\ gcd(b, a) = 1$. Prove that $\gcd(b + a, b − a) \leq 2$](/q/987515).

Comment: Thanks lulu and John, I think I got it now :)