# GCF of $A= 14a+4b$ and $B=11a+3b$ , with $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ and GCF$(a,b)= d$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Source : Oudot, *Maths MPSI* , Hachette (ed.) ,exercice $6$,  p. $195$.

---

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, and $d = $ GCF$(a,b)$. Let
$A= 14a+4b$ and $B=11a+3b$.
Question : determine GCF$(A,B)$.

---

This is a very basic exercice , but I'm stuck.

- I want to apply this theorem : For all $n \in \mathbb Z$

> $n$ can be written as $n= a u + bv$ iff $n$ is a multiple of
> GCF$(a,b)$

with $u, v \in \mathbb Z$.

- What I get is that, since $A= 14a+4b$ and $B=11a+3b$, it follows that : $A= kd$ and $B= k'd$ , with $ k, k' \in \mathbb Z$ and $ d =$ GCF$(a,b)$.
- Also $A+B = 24 a + 7b = k'' d$
- Out of this follows that : $kd + k'd = k'' d$ , implying that $ (k+k')d = k''d$ , and finally $k+k' = k''$.

But I don't see what I can draw from this regarding the original question.

Comment: Why don't you use Euclid's algorithm to simply $\gcd(14a+4b, 11a + 3b) = \gcd(3a+b, 11a+3b)= \gcd(3a+b,2a)=\gcd(a+b,2a)=\gcd(a+b, a-b)$?

Comment: Thanks for this hint!

Comment: As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32894/242) in the dupe $\ (a,b)\mid (A,B)\mid 2(a,b)\ \ $